# How to read cassandra data with out case sensitive

Tags: cassandra

I need to get the data from cassandra with out case sensitive. Please help me.

Answer (score 10):

There is no case-sensitivity concept in Cassandra. All the data is stored as `byte[]`, so it's not even a String.

You can make a custom comparator ([see the API](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/API)) which transforms `byte[]` to String and disregards case.

The other thing to do is just get the data and transform it on the client side.

Actually, your question is quite unclear as of what is your goal, so I can't give more details.

**Update:** Run a one-time job that fetches all records from the db and updates them, setting to lower-case. Then continue inserting everything with lowercase.

Comment: Actually i have saved data in cassandra with lower case . But unfortunately, while updating the data, i forgot to change the case. So now the data is mixed up(lower+upper). now i need to retrieve all the data in lower case. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved if you have SOLR enabled using:
CREATE SEARCH INDEX ON tableName WITH COLUMNS *, camelCaseColumn { lowerCase : true };

An index is created that allows the select statement to use lowercase in the where clause.  For more details search for LowerCaseStrField.

Comment: Please consider adding a reference to the documentation which always helps.