# Cassandra WHERE - Compare case-insensitive

Tags: text, cassandra, cql

So I have a table with a username column (text).

Now I want to get a user by it's username but I want to perform the search case-insensitive.

In SQL you would do it like that:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE UPPER(username) = UPPER('foo');
```

But in CQL, there are no functions like UPPER or LOWER so how would I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this thread: [How to read cassandra data with out case sensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649979/how-to-read-cassandra-data-with-out-case-sensitive)

There are no features to check case sensitivity in Cassandra. Ideally you should write all the data through your application in lower case and stick with that. You could write a job to retrieve and update all the data as lower case as a once off.

Comment: Alright thank you. Since I need to have store the username with the real cases, I'm gonne make a second column.